# Make a common column value as the heading of all results in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, sorting, heading

I want to retrieve data from mysql database, but all i need is to make the common value of the data as the heading of all the retrieved data
example of the table:
**ID | Name | orderDate**  |
1  | John   | 10-07-2019 |
2  | Maige | 10-07-2019 |
3  | Allyc   | 10-07-2019 |
4  | Diana | 11-07-2019 |
5  | Selen | 11-07-2019 |
6  | Jacky | 12-07-2019 |

So I want my results to appear like this

**10 - 07- 2019**
1. John
2. Maige
3. Allyc
**11 - 07- 2019**
4. Diana
5. Selen
**12 - 07- 2019**
6. Jacky
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Store dates as dates, and seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You should  do this in the front end, not the db-in OO programming terms, think of rows as instances of an object. Creating fake objects of a completely different type and inserting them into the list for purely presentational reasons is an ugly hack..

```
SELECT sho FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 0 as ord, orderdate, DATE_FORMAT(orderdate, '%d - %m - %y') as sho FROM orders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id as ord, orderdate, CONCAT(id, '. ', name) as sho FROM orders
) x
ORDER BY orderdate, ord
```

Ugh. So we generate some fake rows with s formatted date, the date (as a date) and a 0 (lower than an id) and union them with the real data date, id and s formatted text. When this lot of data (fake plus real) is sorted by date then ord the fake rows that form the "header" come out first, then the data, then the next header

Please do this on the front end